# Quantative and statistical data in Critical Discourse Analysis

Tags: discourse-analysis

In the context of my thesis, I am applying Norman Fairclough's 3-stage model of textual analysis to a corpus of governmental documents I have collected. I want to prove the existence of ideology behind some specific linguistic choices (e.g. use of archaisms or fossil words)
I know CDA is a qualitative method of research so I wonder how I should handle quantitative/statistical data in my analysis. Should I avoid them, rely heavily on them or use them supplementary to my conclusions?
Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: A mixed method (taken from sociology) is explained in this paper. How to use quantative data to arrive at qualitative results. It also gives a step by step approach to these issues: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/emre.12452

Comment: Thank you so much for your contribution! It will be of much help!

Answer (score 1):

From my own experience in academia I would suggest to check with your supervisor. Some people are very hung up on only using certain methods that are traditional in a discipline, and will not like innovation, especially when it comes to quantitative methods; I had an Engish Lit professor ask me where the meaning was in the correlation formula I used for an assignment on Australian short stories.

My personal view would be to use them to support (or derive) your conclusions from, but as I said, I'm not marking your thesis and you should check with the people who do.